# ReactNative + Nested navigation – navigating directly to the nested screen

Tags: react-native

This is my current code that I'm calling from `home` route (when pressing a button):

```
navigation.navigate('menu', {
  initial: false,
  screen: 'menu/sessions',
  params: {
    initial: false,
    screen: 'menu/sessions/record',
    params: {
      sessionId: session.id,
    },
  },
})
```

As expected, it goes to `menu/sessions/record`.

Yet, when the back button is pressed, it goes back to `menu/sessions` first, then `menu`, and then `home`.

Is there a way I can skip the `menu/sessions` and `menu` when going back?

Comment: Have you tried navigation.popToTop() ?

Answer (score 0):

Do the '**home', 'menu', 'menu/sessions',** and **'menu/sessions/record'** screens all exist in one Navigator?

If you want to go from the **'home'** screen to the **'menu/sessions/record'** screen, separate the **'menu', 'menu/sessions', and 'menu/sessions/record'** screens into separate Navigators.

Please refer to the link below.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/